# How to improve accuracy of model for categorical, non-binary, foreign language sentiment analysis in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

### TLDR

My aim is to categorize sentences in a foreign language (Hungarian) to 3 sentiment categories: *negative, neutral & positive*. I would like to **improve the accuracy of the model used**, which can be found below in the "**Define, Compile, Fit the Model**" section. The rest of the post is here for completeness and reproducibility.

*I am new to asking questions on Machine Learning topics, suggestions are welcome here as well: [How to ask a good question on Machine Learning?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399477/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-machine-learning)*

---

### Data preparation

For this I have 10000 sentences, given to 5 human annotators, categorized as negative, neutral or positive, available from [here](http://metashare.nytud.hu/repository/browse/hungarian-opinion-tagged-sentence-bank/608756be64e211e2aa7c68b599c26a068dd5b3551f024f6281131670412d37d3/). The first few lines look like this:

[image]

I categorize the sentence positive (denoted by `2`) if sum of the scores by annotators is positive, neutral if it is 0 (denoted by `1`), and negative (denoted by `0`) if the sum is negative:

```
import pandas as pd
sentences_df = pd.read_excel('/content/OpinHuBank_20130106.xls')

sentences_df['annotsum'] = sentences_df['Annot1'] +\
                           sentences_df['Annot2'] +\
                           sentences_df['Annot3'] +\
                           sentences_df['Annot4'] +\
                           sentences_df['Annot5']

def categorize(integer):
    if 0 < integer:  return 2
    if 0 == integer: return 1
    else: return 0

sentences_df['sentiment'] = sentences_df['annotsum'].apply(categorize)
```

Following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn), I use [SubwordTextEncoder](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/SubwordTextEncoder) to proceed. From [here](http://mokk.bme.hu/resources/webcorpus/), I download `web2.2-freq-sorted.top100k.nofreqs.txt`, which contains `100000` most frequently used word in the target language. (Both the sentiment data and this data was recommended by [this](https://github.com/oroszgy/awesome-hungarian-nlp).)

Reading in list of most frequent words:

```
wordlist = pd.read_csv('/content/web2.2-freq-sorted.top100k.nofreqs.txt',sep='\n',header=None,encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')[0].dropna()
```

---

### Encoding data, conversion to tensors

Initializing encoder using [build_from_corpus](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/SubwordTextEncoder#build_from_corpus) method:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
encoder = tfds.features.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
        corpus_generator=(word for word in wordlist), target_vocab_size=2**16)
```

Building on this, encoding the sentences:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def applyencoding(string):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.asarray(encoder.encode(string)))
sentences_df['encoded_sentences'] = sentences_df['Sentence'].apply(applyencoding)
```

[Convert to a tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) each sentence's sentiment:

```
def tensorise(input):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(input)
sentences_df['sentiment_as_tensor'] = sentences_df['sentiment'].apply(tensorise)
```

Defining how much data to be preserved for testing:

```
test_fraction = 0.2
train_fraction = 1-test_fraction
```

From the `pandas dataframe`, let's create `numpy array` of encoded sentence train tensors:

```
nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors = \
        np.asarray(sentences_df['encoded_sentences'][:int(train_fraction*len(sentences_df['encoded_sentences']))])
```

These tensors have different lengths, so lets use [padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences) to make them have the same:

```
padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
                                            nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors, padding="post")
```

Let's [stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) these tensors together:

```
stacked_padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors = tf.stack(padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors)
```

Stacking the sentiment tensors together as well:

```
stacked_nparray_sentiment_train_tensors = \
        tf.stack(np.asarray(sentences_df['sentiment_as_tensor'][:int(train_fraction*len(sentences_df['encoded_sentences']))]))
```

---

### Define, Compile, Fit the Model (ie the main point)

Define & compile the model as follows:

```
### THE QUESTION IS ABOUT THESE ROWS ###
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, 64),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 5, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
]) 
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fit it:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 40
history = model.fit(stacked_padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_train_tensors,
                    stacked_nparray_sentiment_train_tensors,
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

The first few lines of the output is:

[image]

---

### Testing results

As in [TensorFlow's RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_classification_rnn), let's plot the results we gained so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graphs(history):
  plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
  plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
  plt.xlabel("Epochs")
  plt.ylabel('accuracy / loss')
  plt.legend(['accuracy','loss'])
  plt.show()

plot_graphs(history)
```

Which gives us:

[image]

Prepare the testing data as we prepared the training data:

```
nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors = \
        np.asarray(sentences_df['encoded_sentences'][int(train_fraction*len(sentences_df['encoded_sentences'])):])

padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(
                                                 nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors, padding="post")

stacked_padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors = tf.stack(padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors)

stacked_nparray_sentiment_test_tensors = \
        tf.stack(np.asarray(sentences_df['sentiment_as_tensor'][int(train_fraction*len(sentences_df['encoded_sentences'])):]))
```

Evaluate the model using only test data:

```
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(stacked_padded_nparrayof_encoded_sentence_test_tensors,stacked_nparray_sentiment_test_tensors)
print('Test Loss: {}'.format(test_loss))
print('Test Accuracy: {}'.format(test_acc))
```

Giving result:
[image]

Full notebook available [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qIbvy7ZPJjEBp2m7d3c0ZS4sQhst3TBa?usp=sharing).

---

### The question

**How can I change the model definition and compilation rows above to have higher accuracy on the test set after no more than 1000 epochs?**

Answer (score 2):

1. You are using word piece subwords, you can try BPE. Also, you can build your model upon BERT and use transfer learning, that will literally skyrocket your results.
2. Firstly, change the kernel size in your Conv1D layer and try various values for it. Recommended would be [3, 5, 7]. Then, consider adding layers. Also, in the second last layer i.e. Dense, increase the number of units in it, that might help. Alternately, you can try a network with just LSTM layers or LSTM layers followed by Conv1D layer.
3. By trying out if it works then great otherwise repeat. But, the training loss gives a hint about it, if you see, the loss is not going down smoothly, you may assume, that your network is lacking predictive power i.e. underfitting and increase the number of neurons in it.
4. Yes, more data does help. But, if the fault is in your network i.e. it is underfitting, then, it won't help. First, you should explore the limits of the model you have before looking for faults in the data.
5. Yes, using the most common words is the usual norm because probabilistically, the less used words won't occur more and thus, won't affect the predictions greatly.